# Need a little hint/help with describing sets

Tags: calculus

Question: Let $A = \{x\in \Bbb Z\mid x\gt 0\}$, $B = \{x\in \Bbb Z\mid x\lt 0\}$, $C =\{2n\mid n\in \Bbb Z\}$ and $D =\{3n\mid n\in\Bbb Z \}$. Describe the following sets with mathematical symbols:

- $a)$ $A\cup B$

For $a)$ I was thinking this way:

$A\cup B = \{x\in \Bbb N, -\Bbb N \mid x\in A \text{ or } x\in B\}$.

I am not sure if correct or completely wrong

Thanks for helping.

If interested here are the next ones, but I am only asking to give me a hint on the first one.

- $b)$ $A\cup B\cup C\cup D$
- $c)$ $A\cap B$
- $d)$ $C\cap B$
- $e)$ $A\cap (C\cup D)$

Thanks you.

Comment: I don' t think there is a notation $-\mathbb{N}$. Since $A\cup B$ is the set of all integers except $0$, this is better represented by $\mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: @KittyL
Thank you
So: 
A U B = { x ∈ Z | x ∈ A or x∈B }. (Z = integer)

Correct?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA no he thankfully didn't

Comment: no. it is $A\cup B=\{x\in \Bbb Z-\{0\} \}$

Comment: No, you don't need to say $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. Just $\mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$ or Subhadeep Dey's answer.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Why SubhadeepDey?? Could you give me an explanation

Comment: @KittyL
Z∖{0} --- does it mean that x ist in Z but not zero?
A U B = {x∈Z\{0}}

Comment: Yes, it means $x$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not $0$. You can directly write $A\cup B=\mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$ since they are both sets, or you can write $A\cup B=\{x| x\in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\} \}$.

Comment: @user13132, I think your concept is not clear. $A$ and $B$  are  sets of positive and negative integers respectively. so both does not contain $0$. so their union will be set of integers excluding $0$.

Comment: @KittyL ,@SubhadeepDey
Your are the best guys thanks alot

Comment: @SubhadeepDey
Thank you, I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\cup B=\Bbb Z-\{0\}$

$A\cup B \cup C\cup D=\Bbb Z $

$A\cap B=\phi$

$C\cap B=\{2n|n\in \Bbb Z \;\text {and}\;n\lt 0\}$

$A\cap(C\cup D)=\{6n|n\in \Bbb N,n\gt 0\}$

Comment: Thank you SubhadeepDey ,but could you give me a short explanation to each one of them, that would enlighten me?

Comment: @user13132, you just think yourself.For $A\cup B\cup C\cup D$,Read carefully the definitions, so $A$ and $B$ are positive and negative integers, and their union as I told earlier. Now, look that $0$ is both multiple of $2$ and $3$. and other multiples of $2$ and $3$ are positive and negative integers. So, their union will be the entire set if integers. analogously, think out of other results, and inform me if you encounter complexity. Try hard.

Comment: Thanks again and for the motivation SubhadeepDey
Yes, if I find out something i will.

Comment: I did. The other sets, i thought you already did the other ones.
A∩B=ϕ --> could i write this for {x| x∈ϕ}?
The reason why A∩B=ϕ is, because A and B are integers and area in between (drawing a Venn graph ) does not exist, which would be 0 and zero is not an integer.
Correct?

Comment: I dont quite get C∩B={2n|n∈Zandn≤0}
I understood that 2n is because of the multiples of 2 (n= 1,2,-3,-4.......) and when you put 2 in front you get the multiples of 2, then we say that n "a" integer. After this part i dont get it----- n≤0

Why is n smaller equal to zero ((smaller because of the negative interger) B ? but why zero)
Thanks

Comment: @question, you are right. I edited a bit. Look this.

Comment: @question,$A\cap B=\phi$ because, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $A$ is set of positive integers and $B$ is set of negative integers. So their intersection is void, because $0\notin A$ and $0\notin B$. So, $0$ is not in their intersection. But $0$ is an integer, but neither $-ve$ nor $+ve$.